# cURL connection closes on http status 200(OK)

Tags: c++, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to connect server and get response with curl but when data starting transfer curl drop connection. Can anyone say me whats going wrong ?

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sat, 15 Feb 2014 02:08:27 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 200 OK
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< ETag: "e283c3fc75aa2172d77a717ecbb49b41"
< Set-Cookie: remember_token=BAhbB2kCyVsiRTUxMmI2MzQwOTk5MGU2ZDU3NmMxMmRjY2UxZTI0ODgzNzJmOGRlNzFlNzZjMWExZWM3NTA3OWJjY2E0NmQ5Mjc%3D--1e016eb43ab4803ac65211ddd383ddeeaf9b53f2; path=/; expires=Wed, 15-Feb-2034 02:08:26 GMT
< Set-Cookie: _gameserver2250_session=BAh7BiIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlYzIxNGNlNTExNjYwNDg0MTU0YWJkOGQ2ZWI1ZDI3ZTk%3D--f9c25e0cd8d94283b01056e9aeff46a1feb48d6b; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Runtime: 1.249006
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Curl seems to be saying that it's the server that's closing the connection.

Comment: thanks for reply i figure out that server wanted some data to be sent!!

Comment: Were u able to solve the issue? If yes, that change u made?